# React Drag and Drop with grid layout

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am creating Drag and Drop with grid layout in React. In handleDragStart I'm updating state which causes rerendering which then prevent further execution.

```
    const handleDragStart = (widget: IWidget): void => {
            setDraggingWidget(widget);
            const widgetIndex = widgetState.findIndex((item) => item.id === widget.id);
            if (widgetIndex !== -1) {
                const updatedWidgets = [...widgetState];
                updatedWidgets.splice(widgetIndex, 1);
                updatedWidgets.splice(targetIndex, 0, {id: -1, name: 'ghostWidget', elements: [],     orderPriority: targetIndex});
            setWidgetState(updatedWidgets);
        }
    };

    const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedWidgets = [...widgetState];
        updatedWidgets.splice(targetIndex, 0, draggingWidget);
        const ghostWidgetIndex = updatedWidgets.findIndex((item) => item.id === -1);
        updatedWidgets.splice(ghostWidgetIndex, 1);
        updatedWidgets.forEach((item, index) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            item.orderPriority = index;
        });
        setWidgetState(updatedWidgets);
        dispatch(editMultipleWidgetsSagaAction(updatedWidgets));
    };
```

How can I change that but still have live state because of div which displays for widgets with id -1? That id -1 is empty space in grid, somehow, preview where will dragging item be dropped.